# How to filter based on two arguments from php, in a SQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

I have a MySQL database, and the table I need to work with has 9 columns of information. My goal is to be able to filter, based on two arguments. For instance, the table is about students so it has data for first name, last name, id, course they are signed up for, status, occupation age and another 2 fields that are not that important. I need to be able to filter, based on the student's status and/or the course.

So far, I managed to get the php work done, with a form and a select tag, to filter based on status, but I have no idea how to add the second part. The done thing should be able to filter, based on status only, based on course only, or based on the selected status and course. The code looks like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['filter'])) {
        $search_term = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['filter_status']);
        $q .= " WHERE status = '$search_term'";
    }
    echo $q;
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
    <select name="filter_status" > 
        <option value="confirmed">confirmed</option>
        <option value="declined">declined</option>
        <option value="rejected">rejected</option>
        <option value="pending">pending</option>
        <option value="unconfirmed">unconfirmed</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="filter">
</form>
```

This works correctly, I have it a second time for the second criteria, but they don't work together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your input. It helped nudge me in the right direction. The code that ended up doing what I needed is as follows. It's not very elegant, but it does the job well:

```
$q = "SELECT *
FROM students";

if (isset($_POST['filter'])) {
    if ($_POST['filter_status'] == null) {
    $search_term2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['filter_course']);
    $q .= " WHERE course = '$search_term2'";
} elseif ($_POST['filter_course'] == null) {
    $search_term = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['filter_status']);
    $q .= " WHERE status = '$search_term'";
} else {
    $search_term = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['filter_status']);
    $search_term2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['filter_course']);
    $q .= " WHERE status = '$search_term' AND course = '$search_term2'";
}

}
```

And the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
    <select name="filter_status" > 
        <option value= ""></option>
        <option value="confirmed">confirmed</option>
        <option value="declined">declined</option>
        <option value="rejected">rejected</option>
        <option value="pending">pending</option>
        <option value="unconfirmed">unconfirmed</option>
    </select>

    <select name="filter_course">
    <option value= ""></option> 
        <option value="php">php</option>
        <option value="java">java</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="filter">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to change,

```
$q .= " WHERE status = '$search_term'";
```

to

```
$q .= " WHERE CONCAT_WS(',',status,course) like %'$search_term'%";
```

you can add as many columns after course.

Comment: this looks great. But I have to have 2 drop down lists with the 2 columns, should the second list also be outputting to $search_term?

Comment: just add another `like %'$search_term'%"` part e.g. `AND like %'$search_term_2'%"` for your second list but you can name it like whatever you want

Comment: Or if  you want to allow one filter at a time use `OR like %'$search_term_2'%"`

Answer (score 1):

`$filter_status = $_POST['filter_status'];
    $course = $_POST['course'];
    $where = 'WHERE 1';
    $where .= $filter_status ? " AND status = {$filter_status}" : '';
    $where .= $course ? " AND course = {$course}" : '';`

Did you mean this? when user select course and filter_status use this two conditions, on the other hand use one of conditions which is being selected.

The `WHERE 1` will always be `TRUE`, so it can be followed by `AND` statements

Comment: Yes, I think so. User must be able to select just one filter, say filter by status, or filter by course, or to be able to select both. I added blank fields to my form, the thing you wrote above should complete the picture. Testing it now. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Use the term `AND` or `OR` in your query after `WHERE`

```
WHERE status = '$search_term' AND course = '$something'
```

Comment: it has to be AND and OR. There has to be an option, where the user can filter both based on status and on course, also, he has to be able to filter based on just one, so it has to be AND and OR. Was thinking, If I have two queries, and the form data is in an if statement, where if one select field is empty, just use data from the second one, if both have data selected, filter like you said, with both queries and AND in the WHERE statement of the query, but I don't know if that will work.